# SMBJ no longer working when I modify JMX port settings

Tags: rmi, jmx, datadog, smbj

I have an application running under spring boot utilizing SMBJ to mount and read remote files, and it works perfectly.   However I am trying to set up some datadog reporting and trying to use JMX as a datasource for datadog...

TO do this I am staring the springboot jar with the following:

```
 ENTRYPOINT java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myhost 
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8089 
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8089 
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
     -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And once I do this, SMBJ no longer creates the mount.  If I remove these parameters the code works fine again and SMBJ is able to create/mount to the share, If I have them it simply times out trying to create the share.  I thought maybe it was the RMI hostname change, but removing just this this doesn't seem to fix it.

Can anyone offer any help on this?  Is SMBJ really dependent on the jmxremote settings?   It certainly seems to be..I have tried removing the overriding of the ports, so they go to their default ports as well, but this didn't fix it either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SMBJ is not reliant on any JMX settings. Do you have any log output?

Comment: It was a problem related to network config.. i was running with this config in a docker compose with multiple instances, which created a docker network that didn't have the proper configurations... when I ran the image directly it inherited the host network stuff and worked fine.  So you are correct, it wasn't anything related to SMBJ and the JMX stuff.